# Read specific line from a file with stream

Tags: c#, stream

I want to monitor my iis logs files, to do that I read them with :

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    client.send(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
```

And then send lines to my database. I also use a FileSystemWatcher to detect changes and sending new lines by using a index dictionnary (key:file path, value:last line).
The problem with the streamreader is that I don't know how to get a specific line. I was using File.ReadAllLines(file path) before, where it was simple to get the specific line as it was an array, but I moved to the streamreader because I was getting exceptions (the file is used by another process).

EDIT : Thanks for your answer, it works perfectly. I would like to know if it's possible, with the same idea, to still get the specific new line and all the new lines added after this line until the end of the stream. (Because a newly added log can be written on multiple lines)

Answer (score -1):

Since you can't predict the location (can you?) of the i-th line in the file, you'll have to read all previous lines too. If the line number is small, this can be more efficient than the ReadAllLines method. Try this

```
string GetLine(string fileName, int line)
{
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
       for (int i = 1; i < line; i++)
          sr.ReadLine();
       return sr.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: No I can predict the location, I know exactly the position of my new line added. But I don't know how to use this position with the stream as it's not a simple array.

Comment: @user2443476 By "position" do you mean the line number or the offset in bytes of the first character from the start of the file?

Comment: Ok if your position is just the line you can use what i suggest